# Conditional to render bootstrap row class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on a personal MVC project using ASP.Net MVC where I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
      @foreach(var item in @Model)
      { 
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                 //TODO... Render html here
            </div>
         </div>
      }
   </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to render the row class after every 3th iteration. So, the idea is to have something like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">HTML HERE</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">HTML HERE</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">HTML HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="row">   -->render this if the after the 3th iteration in the foreach
   <div class="col-md-4">HTML HERE</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">HTML HERE</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">HTML HERE</div>
</div>
```

I was trying to create a variable in razor @{int i=0;} and use it in a if statement like this:

```
@if(i%3 == 0){
   //render the row class
   <div class="row">
}
```

But, I am getting some compile errors.

Has anyone do something similar? Or do you know if it's possible to do that in ASP.Net MVC using Razor?

Regards!

Comment: The content inside `<div class="col-md-4">` is always static html ? nothing from the model item ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options

1. If entire block of  and its children are to be rendered at regular intervals

   ```
      @{
        int index = 0;
       }
       @foreach (var item in @Model)
       {
         if(index % 3 == 0)
         { 
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4">
                @* //TODO... Render html here*@
               </div>
          </div>
         }

         index++;
       }
   ```
2. If the children are to be rendered every time but only the  has to be rendered at regular intervals

   ```
       @{
         int index = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in @Model)
        {
          if (index % 3 == 0)
          {
             @:  <div class="row">
          }

          <div class="col-md-4">
             @* //TODO... Render html here*@
          </div>

          if (index % 3 == 0)
          {
             @:     </div>
          }        

          index++;
       }
   ```

Comment: I used the 2nd option. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the collection and render it. Keep a counter to check the column count and use that in the loop to determine whether a new row should start.

```
<div>
    @{
        var numberOfColsNeeded = 3;
        var totalCounter = Model.Count();
        var itemCounter = 1;
    }

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (itemCounter % numberOfColsNeeded == 1)
        {
            @:<div class="row">
        }
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span>Some html</span>
            <span> @item.Name</span>
        </div> 
        if ((itemCounter % numberOfColsNeeded == 0) || ((itemCounter) == totalCounter))
        {
            @:</div>
        }
        itemCounter++;
    }
</div>
```